# If $G$ acts on conjugation on its power set, what is the set of fixed points? What is the kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am learning about group actions and experimenting with different actions. One common action I see is acting by conjugation on the power set.

From this action we get the stabilizer of a set $A \subset G$ is its normalizer: $\{g \in G \mid gAg^{-1}=A\}=N_G(A)$.

The set of fixed points is $\{A \in \mathcal P(G) \mid gAg^{-1}=A \text{ for all } g \in G\}$. **Can we say something more about this set?** I see that if we instead act on the set of subgroups, then the set of fixed points is the set of normal subgroups.

The kernel is $\{g \in G \mid gAg^{-1}=A \text{ for all } A \in \mathcal P(G)\}$. So, $g \in N_G(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal(G)$. **Can we say something more about this set?**  Is the kernel just the union of all the normalizers? The kernel is normal and so it is the union of conjugacy classes. Which conjugacy classes?

Answer (score 1):

For the set of fixed points, I don't think there's much you can generally say, but such points are sometimes called normal subsets of $G$. It's not hard to show that these are unions of conjugacy classes.

For the kernel, I'll give a hint. If $g$ is in the kernel, then for all $x\in G$ you have $\{x\}=\{x\}^g=\{x^g\}$. What does this tell you about $g$?

Comment: If $x,g \in G$, what is $x^g$?

Comment: @AlJebr: $x^g = g^{-1}xg$, ${}^gx = gxg^{-1}$. The notation is suggestive because, for example, $(x^g)^h = x^{gh}$.

Comment: @AlJebr Apologies, I'm used to right action notation, but the above comment is correct, $x^g=g^{-1}xg$. You can  use the hint $\{x\}=g\{x\}g^{-1}=\{gxg^{-1}\}$ if you prefer.